# rolling join two time series in data.table

Tags: r, join, time-series, data.table

Suppose one has two asynchronous time-series in `data.table`:

```
dt1 = setkey(data.table(k = 2*(1:4) + 1, v = c(10, 15, 9, 7)), k)
dt2 = setkey(data.table(k = 2*(1:3), v = c(11, 13, 6)), k)
```

My desired output is to merge them on `k` column using LOCF and all values of `k` from `dt1` and `dt2`, like so:

```
> out
k v i.v
2 NA 11
3 10 11
4 10 13
5 15 13
6 15 6
7 9  6
9 7  6
```

Currently, I am using a somewhat clumsy construction:

```
all_keys = setkey(data.table(k = sort(c(dt1[, k], dt2[, k])), k)
dt1[all_keys, roll = T, on = 'k'][
    dt2[all_keys, roll = T, on = 'k']]
```

This works, but feels a little contrived. Note that a simple rolling `dt1[dt2, roll = T]` or `dt2[dt1, roll = T]` would ignore keys from either `dt1` or `dt2`.
Is there a simpler way?

P.S. Side note - is there also a simpler way to create a keyed `data.table` from the beginning just using `data.table` function, without following up with a setkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `merge` with `all=T` and `setnafill` with `type='locf'`:

```
setnafill(merge(dt1,dt2,all=T),type="locf")[]

Key: <k>
       k   v.x   v.y
   <num> <num> <num>
1:     2    NA    11
2:     3    10    11
3:     4    10    13
4:     5    15    13
5:     6    15     6
6:     7     9     6
7:     9     7     6
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, seems like a decent alternative. Probably would need something like an `lapply` + `.SDcols` if I have many `v` columns in practice, right?

Comment: An option could be not to use `cols` argument at all, it works because the key doesn't have `NA` anyway, see my edit